# What is Bayes' theorem?

Tags: machine-learning, math, definitions, statistics, bayes-theorem

What is Bayes' theorem? How does it relate to conditional probabilities?

Comment: checkout this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/672/what-is-bayes-theorem-all-about. You can find more about bayes theorem on stats exchange

Answer (score 2):

[Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) relates conditional probabilities:

$$P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(B \mid A) P(A)}{P(B)}$$